# How to express the trend in this graph using the appropriate phrases?

Tags: phrases, expressions, comparisons

I have this graph and I want to describe the difference in the take off trajectory of two patterns in the figure below.
The first pattern is seen in the first two parameters over the years from the left.
The second pattern is seen in the next 4 parameters.
I wanted to describe the beginning part of these two patterns. How to describe this using appropriate phrases?

My trial:

> The first two parameters (a and b) *took off faster* than the next 4 parameters (c, d, e and f).
>
> The 4 parameters (c, d, e and f) showed *a modest take off* compared with the first two (a and b).

**Update:**

> While A and B showed *a sharp incremental trajectory*, the initial slope was rather *shallow* for C, D , E and F.

[image: Example graph]

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematical term, a technical term, a metaphor, or something else?

Comment: a technical term and a metaphor, to express the difference between the two patterns of take of.

Comment: Perhaps the key thing to note about these trends is that A and B rise in the early 1990s, while C, D, E, and F only begin to rise, at a much slower rate, in the early 2000s.

Comment: True, but I am not interested in the *year* these parameters started to take off, since these years are actually the years of their discovery. I am rather interested in the rate of their increase right after their discovery. The *at a much slower rate* is very near to what I want, but how to compare between the two using this bit of a phrase?

Comment: Sharp rate of increase versus gradual rate of increase?

Comment: the first part, no doubt fits the bill, but the second part: I think gradual rate is insufficient. Can shallow mean both gradual and *concave*?

Answer (score 1):

I think the technical term you are looking for is **"slope"**.  The "takeoff" slope could be expressed as **"initial slope"** or **"first-stage slope"**

Comment: +1 for the term, but how would you put it in a sentence to show the difference between the two *initial slopes*?

Comment: initial trajectory may be?

Answer (score 1):

"A and B rose quickly while C, D, E, and F remained flat/unchanged during the 90's and early 00's."

Comment: +1, I don't think the 4 parameters remained flat/unchanged, since there was some kind of rising but slower than the first 2. So still I miss the correct term.